# How to calculate image dimensions from camera parameters?

Tags: image-processing, image-manipulation

I'm using `Raspberry Pi Camera v1` with the following parameters

```
Sensor size: 3.67 x 2.74 mm (1/4" format)
Pixel Count: 2592 x 1944
Pixel Size: 1.4 x 1.4 um
Lens: f=3.6 mm, f/2.9
Angle of View: 54 x 41 degrees
Field of View: 2.0 x 1.33 m at 2 m
Full-frame SLR lens equivalent: 35 mm
Fixed Focus: 1 m to infinity
```

The default image dimensions is `1920 x 1080 px`. How to determine the image dimensions in metric units based on the given parameters?

Comment: What do you mean by "image size"? Do you mean filesystem size? Size of an object in the image? Image dimensions in some unit other than pixels?

Comment: @mattdm sorry for the confusion. What I mean here is image dimensions in metric units.

Comment: Does the above question answer what you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

That's kind of like asking "How long is a piece of string?". The image is a grid of pixels — it's really just data without any dimension. Arguably, it's "natural" size corresponds to the size of the sensor, with one pixel roughly representing the area of one photosite. But that's awfully tiny, and very very dense (500+ pixels per mm, or about 13,000ppi!), and not likely to be useful for the human eye.

So, you scale it up to whatever size you like. Somewhere above 200ppi those pixels will start to be apparent and blocky — if you print at much larger than 16cm by 9cm, someone looking closely will probably notice. If you're printing to be viewed across the room, or on a "forgiving" medium like canvas, you can probably go to several times that.

(Of course, the optical quality of such a system is probably also not so great, which also suggests keeping the size down.)